# Can we do random write on a HDF file in Python?

Tags: python, hdf5, hdf

I know we can do random read on a HDF file, but can we do random write? I am using erray to append one array to the HDF file at a time, for 1 million arrays.

Thank you!

Comment: Appending to a file doesn't sound very random...

Comment: @RolandSmith I want a shuffled data in a HDF file, but since the array is too large I can only do sequential write to store the data, and then do random read to store the data a new hdf file. I am wondering if I can shuffle the data without creating a new hdf file.